Rust code / decorator to print / capture sourcecode as it runs
I have a main.rs file with the following repeating form
fn main() {

    println!(r#"<CODE BLOCK 1>"#);

    <CODE BLOCK 1>

    println!(r#"<CODE BLOCK 2>"#);

    <CODE BLOCK 2>
    
    ...
}


(I do this to generate a README.md that demos the library.)
The obvious problem is that the function feels twice as long as it might have to and  anytime I make a change to a code block a I need to be sure to change another location.  Also I have to go through each r#"<CODE BLOCK 1>"# and manually escape each { and }.
I feel that I could probably write a decorator for the code blocks that does this escaping and printing.  But I'd be surprised if I'm the first person that has wanted to programmatically print source code (or at least capture a code block as a string somehow).  Does anyone know of anything like this?

You can avoid escaping { and } by putting your string separate from the format string.
println!("{}", "<CODE BLOCK 1>");

You can also use macros to duplicate and stringify the code.
macro_rules! print_code {
    ($($t:tt)*) => {
        println!("{}", stringify!($($t)*));
        $($t)*
    }
}

fn main() {
    print_code! {
        let a = 5;
    }
    print_code! {
        let b = 5;
    }
    print_code! {
        println!("{}", a + b);
    }
}

In Rust, decorators are called attributes. You can make your own attributes using procedural macros. However, you'll need to be careful about where to insert the prints.

Thanks.  It looks like stringify!($($t)*) doesn't preserve formatting (newlines, spacing, one statement per line, etc), which I guess is what we should expect given the warning that in the book that "unlike macros in C and other languages, Rust macros are expanded into abstract syntax trees, rather than string preprocessing".
Anyhow, I might still use this for simpler blocks.

dbg! does something like this for expressions (which code blocks are, though usually you're not really interested in their return type if it's unit ()).
dbg!({
    let a = 5;
});

It does not however preserve the formatting.
